# Update fields in database

Tags: php, mysql

In my admin page i have form where I can edit user page. When I load edit page and the form I also load the info from database because if the fields are empty they will become empty also in database after submit the form.

The problem is with password field. When form is loaded the field for password is `password` and is shown like this `••••••••••••••••••••••••••••••••••••••••` which is encoded password from DB `4d9012b4a77a9524d675dad27c3276ab5705e5e8`. If I don't change password and didn't input same password the field is updated in database and become this `8122c907fcf084364519b613b3ba6a3a88c9f980`.. This is the file for edit

```
// keep track post values
$username= $_POST['username'];
$password = sha1($_POST['password']);
$email = $_POST['email'];   

$fileName  = $_FILES['user_image']['name'];
$tmpName   = $_FILES['user_image']['tmp_name'];
$fileSize  = $_FILES['user_image']['size'];
$fileType  = $_FILES['user_image']['type'];

// make a new image name
$ext = substr(strrchr($fileName, "."), 1);
            // generate the random file name
$randName = date('Y-m-d') . '-' .$fileName;

// save image path
$path = "../../img/".$randName;
if (in_array($fileType, $permitted)) 
{
    $result = move_uploaded_file($tmpName, $path);
        if (!$result) 
        {
            echo "Error uploading image file";
            exit;
        } 
    }                       
    // update data
    $pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    if ($fileName != null && $fileName != '')
    {
        $sql = "UPDATE users set username = ?, password = ?, email = ?, user_image = ? WHERE user_id = ?";
        $q = $pdo->prepare($sql);
        $q->execute(array($username,$password,$email,$path,$user_id));                          
    }
    else
    {
         $sql = "UPDATE users set username = ?, password = ?, email = ? WHERE user_id = ?";
         $q = $pdo->prepare($sql);
         $q->execute(array($username,$password,$email,$user_id));
    }
    if (isset($_POST)) {
        $_SESSION['edited'] = '<center><code>Done!</code></center>';
        } else {
            $_SESSION['edited'] = false;
        }
        header('Location: users.php');                      
    }               
    else 
    {
    $pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM users where user_id = ?";
    $q = $pdo->prepare($sql);
    $q->execute(array($user_id ));
    $data = $q->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    $username = $data['username'];
    $password= sha1($data['password']);
    $email = $data['email'];
    $user_image = $data['user_image'];
    Database::disconnect();
}                           
?>
<form role="form" action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">

<div class="form-group">
  User ID: <b><?php echo $user_id;?></b>
</div>

<!-- Text input-->
<div class="form-group">
  <label for="username">Username</label>
    <input value="<?php echo !empty($username)?$username:'';?>" id="username" name="username"  class="form-control" type="text">
</div>

<!-- File Button --> 
<div class="form-group">
  <label for="user_image">image</label>
    <input  id="userl_mage" name="user_image" class="input-file" type="file" value="<?php echo !empty($user_image)?$user_image:'';?>">
</div>

<!-- File Button -->            
<div class="form-group">
  <label for="password">Password</label>
    <input id="password" name="password" class="form-control" type="password" value="<?php echo !empty($password)?$password:'';?>">
</div>

<!-- Text input-->
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="email">Email</label>
    <input id="email" name="email" class="form-control" type="text" value="<?php echo !empty($email)?$email:'';?>">
</div>
```

What I see as possible fix is to show actual password so when the form is submited and password didn't change to hash same password. But I don't want to see the password.

Any ideas how to make this?

Comment: Let the password field empty. Stored passwords should be kept hashed at any circumstance. Of course you need to check whether or not the password field is set when updating and if it fits your applications password standards.

Comment: In addition to the password related questions I can recommend this article. It explains in a tutorial how you can use blowfish encryption to safely store your passwords. http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/understanding-hash-functions-and-keeping-passwords-safe--net-17577

Comment: Yes Ben, I understand this but I explained under @Arcturil answer why I don't want and need "more advanced" encryption in this system. Thank's for the tutorial btw.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let the password field empty. Stored passwords should be kept hashed at any circumstance. Of course you need to check whether or not the password field is set when updating and if it fits your applications password standards.

In your programming logic, you could use something like the following to ensure the password is posted:

```
if(isset($_POST["password"]) && !empty($_POST["password"])) {
    // update in database
}
else {
    // show error notification
}
```

Note that this allows any password size and is not very secure. But it prevents entering an empty password. For more information about **filtering data**, I think [this](http://www.phpro.org/tutorials/Filtering-Data-with-PHP.html) is a good reference.

Answer (score 2):

Showing actual password is very insecure. You have to record it in plain text in you DB. I suggest you to have a different page to password changes, where you can ask the actual password, and the new one (2 times). Or leave the password field empty to not changes the actual password... put a hint to user in this field. So if the user fill in with something, than you change the password.

Try this:

```
// update data
$pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

if ($fileName != null && $fileName != '') 
    $update_image = ", user_image='".$path."' ";
else
    $update_image = "";


if(isset($_POST["password"]) && !empty($_POST["password"])) 
    $update_password = ", password='".sha1($_POST['password'])."' ";
else
    $update_password = "";

$sql = "UPDATE users set username = ?, email = ? ".
       $update_image.$update_password." WHERE user_id = ?";

$q = $pdo->prepare($sql);
$q->execute(array($username,$email,$user_id));
```

Comment: I want to be on the same page so second page only for password change is not an option. So you basically suggest to not load the password in the field when the form is shown and if is empty field to not update it. Something like what I have for the image field right now in the `if` condition?

Answer (score 2):

Password hashes are, by definition, irreversible (or as close as you can get in cryptography). So showing the hash to the client serves no purpose. Then it sounds like you're hashing the hash when you save it.

First off, never populate the password field for a client. Hashing means you don't have the password anyways

Second, it looks like you're using an older hashing system. Either SHA1 or MD5. Neither are considered secure. PHP now features a much better system for hashing now. It's called [password_hash](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php)

Comment: Yes it's `sha1`. I just wanted to fix this issue I want to show the field for password on edit form but doesn't want to show any password. And the problem is when the field is empty is update with empty in the DB. But I can't figure out how to make for this field condition not to update in DB. For password hash and secure I know. Just this is small project for closed group users 1-5 who will use it and doesn't need such a advanced encryption..

Comment: Ah, the old "But it's just a small project" argument. There's nothing worse than having a "small" project that suddenly gets picked up and turned into something larger. Your real problem is that you need to just not update the password field when it's empty. From your code that's not a tall order.

Comment: Thank's again. Actually after seeing tutorial that Ben send I considered to put hashing function + will check for empty field and not update the table if is empty.